# Why is the data stored in firestore not being fetched in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firestore in react but I get the following in console(no data):

> > t {vf: e, m_: t, xf: null, $f: false, kf: false, …}
> > $f: false
> > T_: null
> > kf: false
> > m_: t {path: n}
> > vf: e {uf: n, hf: e, lf: FirebaseAppImpl, _f: e, INTERNAL: {…}, …}
> > xf: null
> > exists: (...)
> > id: (...)
> > metadata: (...)
> > ref: (...)
> > **proto**: Object

My firebase Setup

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDTpOEQVLZFezpUNDMPmh0FckcQmDQp_rQ",
  authDomain: "ecommerce-app-f6a42.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://ecommerce-app-f6a42.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ecommerce-app-f6a42",
  storageBucket: "ecommerce-app-f6a42.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "455019623318",
  appId: "1:455019623318:web:2d90e3539b53ed939663b7",
  measurementId: "G-BJGR6HPE48",
});

const db = firebaseConfig.firestore();

export default db;
```

Using db to get the data from firestore and consoled it:

```
import db from './firebase';

componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("Products").onSnapshot((snap) => console.log(snap));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is being fetched just fine.  You're logging an object whose contents are obfuscated.

`snap` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) type object.  You should work with it as you see in the linked API documentation.  I also suggest reading the primary product [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) for examples on how to process query results.  Minimally, you should iterate the DocumentSnapshot objects contained in that QuerySnapshot, and consider logging the document data within each one.

Here is an example from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection):

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

Here is another one using a simpler `get()` operation rather than a realtime listener:

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```